# Run a local script in a remote host using tmux on the remote host

Tags: ssh, tmux, openssh

I managed to run a local script through ssh:

```
ssh <user>@<host> 'bash -s' < /path/to/local_script.sh
```

Also managed to run a remote script in a remote machine using tmux:

```
ssh <user>@<host> tmux new-session -d -s <session-name> '/bin/bash  /path/to/script/in/remote/machine.sh'
```

But I would like something like:

```
ssh <user>@<host> tmux new-session -d -s <session-name> 'bash -s' < /path/to/script/in/local/machine.sh
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you managed to do it then your third local command would behave like the first one, i.e. `ssh` would exit only after the remote `bash -s` exits. What is the point of using `tmux` then? For comparison: your second command is "fire and forget", `ssh` exits just after the remote `tmux` client tells the remote tmux server to *start* `/bin/bash …`, without waiting for this `bash` to exit. I can imagine some sane reasons for using `tmux` in the way you want, but what is *your* reason? Why is the first command not good for you? Why is the second command (after `scp` or `sftp`) not good for you?

Comment: IMO, you should just copy the script to the remote machine (e.g. with `scp`) and run it there.   This avoids all manner of annoying quoting-related problems.